# Extract duplicate string from items in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array:

```
result = [
  "205/65 15", 
  "205/65 16", 
  "205/65 17.5"
];
```

And I would like to extract the same string for items in the array, in this case `205/65 1`.

And it should leave the array as:

```
extracted = "205/65 1";

leftover = [
  "5", 
  "6", 
  "7.5"
];
```

`extracted` is a variable the needs to be populated with the duplicate string that was extracted. It is not known before hand.

Comment: What if there are multiple "same strings"? Does it have to start with the "same string" or can it be in the middle?

Comment: @ritaj Has to start with the same string. Meanwhile we don't know the duplicate value that needs to be extracted.

Comment: Do you want to get the longest common substring from the beginning?

Comment: @adiga Correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using `map` through the array, then `filter` out the matching part of the string contents. And then `replace` the string values:

```js
const result = [
  "205/65 15",
  "205/65 16",
  "205/65 17.5"
];

let extracted = '';
const leftover = result.map((singleStr, index, arr) => {
  extracted = singleStr.split('').filter((singleChar, i) => {
    return arr[index + 1] ? singleChar === arr[index + 1].charAt(i) : '';
  }).join('') || extracted;

  return singleStr.replace(extracted, '');
});

console.log(leftover);
```

Comment: I don't know the `extracted` variable before hand. Thats a variable that needs to be populated with the duplicate string.

Answer (score 1):

If the extracted value is always at the beginning of the string, you can easily write a function that iterates over the array and checks for overlaps:

```js
function extractBeginning(arr){
  if(!arr.length)
    return {
      extracted: '', 
      leftover: []
    }
  let extractable = arr[0]
  for(const elem of arr.slice(1)){
    let i = 0
    while(i < extractable.length && extractable[i] === elem[i])
      i++
    extractable = extractable.slice(0, i)
  }
  return {
    extracted: extractable,
    leftover: arr.map(elem => elem.slice(extractable.length))
  }
}

const input = [
  "205/65 15", 
  "205/65 16",
  "205/65 17.5"
];

console.log(extractBeginning(input))
```

Answer (score -1):

It is very, you can use [jQuery.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function for extracting the array and remove the string by use [JavaScript String replace() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) from the array value.

Here is an example:

```
var arr1 = [];
var arr = ["205/65 15", "205/65 16", "205/65 17.5"];

jQuery.each( arr, function( i, val ) {
  alert(val);
  var res = val.replace("205/65 1", "");
  arr1.push(res);
});

console.log(arr1);
```

```js
var arr1 = [];
var arr = ["205/65 15", "205/65 16", "205/65 17.5"];
jQuery.each( arr, function( i, val ) {
  var res = val.replace("205/65 1", "");
  arr1.push(res);
});
console.log(arr1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```